# How to add all countries name in the option box?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I am using HTML to create selection box for add all countries in the option box. But it option box is shown me too long. Anyone can modified my coding to make it option box shorter.My code in the below:

```html
<div class="select-list">
  <select name="course_type" id="course_type">
    <option slected value="">Country</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AO" value="244">Angola (+244)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AI" value="1264">Anguilla (+1264)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AG" value="1268">Antigua &amp; Barbuda (+1268)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AR" value="54">Argentina (+54)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AM" value="374">Armenia (+374)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AW" value="297">Aruba (+297)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AU" value="61">Australia (+61)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AT" value="43">Austria (+43)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AZ" value="994">Azerbaijan (+994)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BS" value="1242">Bahamas (+1242)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BH" value="973">Bahrain (+973)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BD" value="880">Bangladesh (+880)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BB" value="1246">Barbados (+1246)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BY" value="375">Belarus (+375)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BE" value="32">Belgium (+32)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BZ" value="501">Belize (+501)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BJ" value="229">Benin (+229)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BM" value="1441">Bermuda (+1441)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BT" value="975">Bhutan (+975)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BO" value="591">Bolivia (+591)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BA" value="387">Bosnia Herzegovina (+387)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BW" value="267">Botswana (+267)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BR" value="55">Brazil (+55)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BN" value="673">Brunei (+673)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BG" value="359">Bulgaria (+359)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BF" value="226">Burkina Faso (+226)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BI" value="257">Burundi (+257)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KH" value="855">Cambodia (+855)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CM" value="237">Cameroon (+237)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CA" value="1">Canada (+1)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CV" value="238">Cape Verde Islands (+238)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KY" value="1345">Cayman Islands (+1345)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CF" value="236">Central African Republic (+236)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CL" value="56">Chile (+56)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CN" value="86">China (+86)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CO" value="57">Colombia (+57)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KM" value="269">Comoros (+269)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CG" value="242">Congo (+242)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CK" value="682">Cook Islands (+682)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CR" value="506">Costa Rica (+506)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HR" value="385">Croatia (+385)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CU" value="53">Cuba (+53)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CY" value="90392">Cyprus North (+90392)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CY" value="357">Cyprus South (+357)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CZ" value="42">Czech Republic (+42)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DK" value="45">Denmark (+45)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DJ" value="253">Djibouti (+253)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DM" value="1809">Dominica (+1809)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DO" value="1809">Dominican Republic (+1809)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="EC" value="593">Ecuador (+593)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="EG" value="20">Egypt (+20)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SV" value="503">El Salvador (+503)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GQ" value="240">Equatorial Guinea (+240)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ER" value="291">Eritrea (+291)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="EE" value="372">Estonia (+372)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ET" value="251">Ethiopia (+251)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FK" value="500">Falkland Islands (+500)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FO" value="298">Faroe Islands (+298)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FJ" value="679">Fiji (+679)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FI" value="358">Finland (+358)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FR" value="33">France (+33)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GF" value="594">French Guiana (+594)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PF" value="689">French Polynesia (+689)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GA" value="241">Gabon (+241)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GM" value="220">Gambia (+220)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GE" value="7880">Georgia (+7880)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DE" value="49">Germany (+49)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GH" value="233">Ghana (+233)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GI" value="350">Gibraltar (+350)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GR" value="30">Greece (+30)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GL" value="299">Greenland (+299)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GD" value="1473">Grenada (+1473)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GP" value="590">Guadeloupe (+590)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GU" value="671">Guam (+671)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GT" value="502">Guatemala (+502)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GN" value="224">Guinea (+224)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GW" value="245">Guinea - Bissau (+245)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GY" value="592">Guyana (+592)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HT" value="509">Haiti (+509)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HN" value="504">Honduras (+504)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HK" value="852">Hong Kong (+852)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HU" value="36">Hungary (+36)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IS" value="354">Iceland (+354)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India (+91)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ID" value="62">Indonesia (+62)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IR" value="98">Iran (+98)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IQ" value="964">Iraq (+964)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IE" value="353">Ireland (+353)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IL" value="972">Israel (+972)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IT" value="39">Italy (+39)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="JM" value="1876">Jamaica (+1876)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="JP" value="81">Japan (+81)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="JO" value="962">Jordan (+962)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KZ" value="7">Kazakhstan (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KE" value="254">Kenya (+254)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KI" value="686">Kiribati (+686)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KP" value="850">Korea North (+850)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KR" value="82">Korea South (+82)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KW" value="965">Kuwait (+965)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KG" value="996">Kyrgyzstan (+996)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LA" value="856">Laos (+856)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LV" value="371">Latvia (+371)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LB" value="961">Lebanon (+961)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LS" value="266">Lesotho (+266)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LR" value="231">Liberia (+231)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LY" value="218">Libya (+218)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LI" value="417">Liechtenstein (+417)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LT" value="370">Lithuania (+370)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LU" value="352">Luxembourg (+352)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MO" value="853">Macao (+853)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MK" value="389">Macedonia (+389)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MG" value="261">Madagascar (+261)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MW" value="265">Malawi (+265)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MY" value="60">Malaysia (+60)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MV" value="960">Maldives (+960)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ML" value="223">Mali (+223)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MT" value="356">Malta (+356)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MH" value="692">Marshall Islands (+692)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MQ" value="596">Martinique (+596)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MR" value="222">Mauritania (+222)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="YT" value="269">Mayotte (+269)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MX" value="52">Mexico (+52)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FM" value="691">Micronesia (+691)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MD" value="373">Moldova (+373)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MC" value="377">Monaco (+377)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MN" value="976">Mongolia (+976)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MS" value="1664">Montserrat (+1664)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MA" value="212">Morocco (+212)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MZ" value="258">Mozambique (+258)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MN" value="95">Myanmar (+95)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NA" value="264">Namibia (+264)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NR" value="674">Nauru (+674)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NP" value="977">Nepal (+977)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NL" value="31">Netherlands (+31)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NC" value="687">New Caledonia (+687)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NZ" value="64">New Zealand (+64)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NI" value="505">Nicaragua (+505)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NE" value="227">Niger (+227)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NG" value="234">Nigeria (+234)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NU" value="683">Niue (+683)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NF" value="672">Norfolk Islands (+672)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NP" value="670">Northern Marianas (+670)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NO" value="47">Norway (+47)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="OM" value="968">Oman (+968)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PW" value="680">Palau (+680)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PA" value="507">Panama (+507)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PG" value="675">Papua New Guinea (+675)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PY" value="595">Paraguay (+595)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PE" value="51">Peru (+51)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PH" value="63">Philippines (+63)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PL" value="48">Poland (+48)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PT" value="351">Portugal (+351)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PR" value="1787">Puerto Rico (+1787)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="QA" value="974">Qatar (+974)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="RE" value="262">Reunion (+262)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="RO" value="40">Romania (+40)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="RU" value="7">Russia (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="RW" value="250">Rwanda (+250)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SM" value="378">San Marino (+378)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ST" value="239">Sao Tome &amp; Principe (+239)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SA" value="966">Saudi Arabia (+966)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SN" value="221">Senegal (+221)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CS" value="381">Serbia (+381)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SC" value="248">Seychelles (+248)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SL" value="232">Sierra Leone (+232)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SG" value="65">Singapore (+65)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SK" value="421">Slovak Republic (+421)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SI" value="386">Slovenia (+386)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SB" value="677">Solomon Islands (+677)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SO" value="252">Somalia (+252)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ZA" value="27">South Africa (+27)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ES" value="34">Spain (+34)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LK" value="94">Sri Lanka (+94)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SH" value="290">St. Helena (+290)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KN" value="1869">St. Kitts (+1869)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SC" value="1758">St. Lucia (+1758)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SD" value="249">Sudan (+249)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SR" value="597">Suriname (+597)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SZ" value="268">Swaziland (+268)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SE" value="46">Sweden (+46)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CH" value="41">Switzerland (+41)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SI" value="963">Syria (+963)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TW" value="886">Taiwan (+886)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TJ" value="7">Tajikstan (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TH" value="66">Thailand (+66)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TG" value="228">Togo (+228)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TO" value="676">Tonga (+676)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TT" value="1868">Trinidad &amp; Tobago (+1868)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TN" value="216">Tunisia (+216)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TR" value="90">Turkey (+90)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TM" value="7">Turkmenistan (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TM" value="993">Turkmenistan (+993)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TC" value="1649">Turks &amp; Caicos Islands (+1649)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TV" value="688">Tuvalu (+688)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="UG" value="256">Uganda (+256)</option>
    <!-- <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK (+44)</option> -->
    <option data-countryCode="UA" value="380">Ukraine (+380)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AE" value="971">United Arab Emirates (+971)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="UY" value="598">Uruguay (+598)</option>
    <!-- <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">USA (+1)</option> -->
    <option data-countryCode="UZ" value="7">Uzbekistan (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VU" value="678">Vanuatu (+678)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VA" value="379">Vatican City (+379)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VE" value="58">Venezuela (+58)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VN" value="84">Vietnam (+84)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VG" value="84">Virgin Islands - British (+1284)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VI" value="84">Virgin Islands - US (+1340)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="WF" value="681">Wallis &amp; Futuna (+681)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="YE" value="969">Yemen (North)(+969)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="YE" value="967">Yemen (South)(+967)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ZM" value="260">Zambia (+260)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ZW" value="263">Zimbabwe (+263)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is my CSS style code:

```
   .select-list {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 55px; }

  input, select, textarea {
   outline: none;
  appearance: unset !important;
-moz-appearance: unset !important;
-webkit-appearance: unset !important;
-o-appearance: unset !important;
-ms-appearance: unset !important; }


   input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus {
 outline: none;
box-shadow: none !important;
-moz-box-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
-o-box-shadow: none !important;
-ms-box-shadow: none !important; }


  input, select {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
border: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ebebeb;
padding: 5px 0;
 color: #222;
margin-bottom: 31px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab'; }
input:focus, select:focus {
 color: #222;
border-bottom: 2px solid #4966b1; }


  ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) {
 background: #4966b1;
 color: #fff; }
```

It show me the output of too long option box in the below:

[image]

Anyone can see my coding which part I get it wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Show your CSS. Also, you misspelled `selected`.

Comment: Edit and add css code

Comment: without the css i would say your select box/container is missing a height and overflow: auto

Answer (score 0):

Set the size attribute of the select?
example: size="3"

I am sure there is something else going on though because your provided CSS is lacking.

good luck

```css
.select-list {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  appearance: unset !important;
  -moz-appearance: unset !important;
  -webkit-appearance: unset !important;
  -o-appearance: unset !important;
  -ms-appearance: unset !important;
}

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -o-box-shadow: none !important;
  -ms-box-shadow: none !important;
}

input,
select {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: #222;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
}

input:focus,
select:focus {
  color: #222;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4966b1;
}

ul li:not(.init):hover,
ul li.selected:not(.init) {
  background: #4966b1;
  color: #fff;
}

It show me the output
```

```html
<div class="select-list">
  <select name="course_type" id="course_type" size="3">
    <option selected value="">Country</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AO" value="244">Angola (+244)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AI" value="1264">Anguilla (+1264)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AG" value="1268">Antigua &amp; Barbuda (+1268)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AR" value="54">Argentina (+54)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AM" value="374">Armenia (+374)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AW" value="297">Aruba (+297)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AU" value="61">Australia (+61)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AT" value="43">Austria (+43)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AZ" value="994">Azerbaijan (+994)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BS" value="1242">Bahamas (+1242)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BH" value="973">Bahrain (+973)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BD" value="880">Bangladesh (+880)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BB" value="1246">Barbados (+1246)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BY" value="375">Belarus (+375)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BE" value="32">Belgium (+32)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BZ" value="501">Belize (+501)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BJ" value="229">Benin (+229)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BM" value="1441">Bermuda (+1441)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BT" value="975">Bhutan (+975)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BO" value="591">Bolivia (+591)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BA" value="387">Bosnia Herzegovina (+387)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BW" value="267">Botswana (+267)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BR" value="55">Brazil (+55)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BN" value="673">Brunei (+673)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BG" value="359">Bulgaria (+359)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BF" value="226">Burkina Faso (+226)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="BI" value="257">Burundi (+257)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KH" value="855">Cambodia (+855)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CM" value="237">Cameroon (+237)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CA" value="1">Canada (+1)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CV" value="238">Cape Verde Islands (+238)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KY" value="1345">Cayman Islands (+1345)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CF" value="236">Central African Republic (+236)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CL" value="56">Chile (+56)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CN" value="86">China (+86)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CO" value="57">Colombia (+57)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KM" value="269">Comoros (+269)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CG" value="242">Congo (+242)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CK" value="682">Cook Islands (+682)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CR" value="506">Costa Rica (+506)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HR" value="385">Croatia (+385)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CU" value="53">Cuba (+53)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CY" value="90392">Cyprus North (+90392)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CY" value="357">Cyprus South (+357)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CZ" value="42">Czech Republic (+42)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DK" value="45">Denmark (+45)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DJ" value="253">Djibouti (+253)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DM" value="1809">Dominica (+1809)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DO" value="1809">Dominican Republic (+1809)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="EC" value="593">Ecuador (+593)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="EG" value="20">Egypt (+20)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SV" value="503">El Salvador (+503)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GQ" value="240">Equatorial Guinea (+240)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ER" value="291">Eritrea (+291)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="EE" value="372">Estonia (+372)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ET" value="251">Ethiopia (+251)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FK" value="500">Falkland Islands (+500)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FO" value="298">Faroe Islands (+298)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FJ" value="679">Fiji (+679)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FI" value="358">Finland (+358)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FR" value="33">France (+33)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GF" value="594">French Guiana (+594)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PF" value="689">French Polynesia (+689)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GA" value="241">Gabon (+241)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GM" value="220">Gambia (+220)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GE" value="7880">Georgia (+7880)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="DE" value="49">Germany (+49)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GH" value="233">Ghana (+233)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GI" value="350">Gibraltar (+350)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GR" value="30">Greece (+30)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GL" value="299">Greenland (+299)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GD" value="1473">Grenada (+1473)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GP" value="590">Guadeloupe (+590)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GU" value="671">Guam (+671)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GT" value="502">Guatemala (+502)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GN" value="224">Guinea (+224)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GW" value="245">Guinea - Bissau (+245)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GY" value="592">Guyana (+592)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HT" value="509">Haiti (+509)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HN" value="504">Honduras (+504)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HK" value="852">Hong Kong (+852)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="HU" value="36">Hungary (+36)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IS" value="354">Iceland (+354)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India (+91)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ID" value="62">Indonesia (+62)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IR" value="98">Iran (+98)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IQ" value="964">Iraq (+964)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IE" value="353">Ireland (+353)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IL" value="972">Israel (+972)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="IT" value="39">Italy (+39)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="JM" value="1876">Jamaica (+1876)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="JP" value="81">Japan (+81)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="JO" value="962">Jordan (+962)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KZ" value="7">Kazakhstan (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KE" value="254">Kenya (+254)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KI" value="686">Kiribati (+686)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KP" value="850">Korea North (+850)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KR" value="82">Korea South (+82)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KW" value="965">Kuwait (+965)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KG" value="996">Kyrgyzstan (+996)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LA" value="856">Laos (+856)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LV" value="371">Latvia (+371)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LB" value="961">Lebanon (+961)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LS" value="266">Lesotho (+266)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LR" value="231">Liberia (+231)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LY" value="218">Libya (+218)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LI" value="417">Liechtenstein (+417)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LT" value="370">Lithuania (+370)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LU" value="352">Luxembourg (+352)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MO" value="853">Macao (+853)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MK" value="389">Macedonia (+389)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MG" value="261">Madagascar (+261)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MW" value="265">Malawi (+265)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MY" value="60">Malaysia (+60)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MV" value="960">Maldives (+960)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ML" value="223">Mali (+223)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MT" value="356">Malta (+356)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MH" value="692">Marshall Islands (+692)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MQ" value="596">Martinique (+596)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MR" value="222">Mauritania (+222)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="YT" value="269">Mayotte (+269)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MX" value="52">Mexico (+52)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="FM" value="691">Micronesia (+691)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MD" value="373">Moldova (+373)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MC" value="377">Monaco (+377)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MN" value="976">Mongolia (+976)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MS" value="1664">Montserrat (+1664)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MA" value="212">Morocco (+212)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MZ" value="258">Mozambique (+258)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="MN" value="95">Myanmar (+95)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NA" value="264">Namibia (+264)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NR" value="674">Nauru (+674)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NP" value="977">Nepal (+977)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NL" value="31">Netherlands (+31)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NC" value="687">New Caledonia (+687)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NZ" value="64">New Zealand (+64)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NI" value="505">Nicaragua (+505)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NE" value="227">Niger (+227)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NG" value="234">Nigeria (+234)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NU" value="683">Niue (+683)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NF" value="672">Norfolk Islands (+672)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NP" value="670">Northern Marianas (+670)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="NO" value="47">Norway (+47)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="OM" value="968">Oman (+968)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PW" value="680">Palau (+680)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PA" value="507">Panama (+507)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PG" value="675">Papua New Guinea (+675)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PY" value="595">Paraguay (+595)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PE" value="51">Peru (+51)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PH" value="63">Philippines (+63)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PL" value="48">Poland (+48)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PT" value="351">Portugal (+351)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="PR" value="1787">Puerto Rico (+1787)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="QA" value="974">Qatar (+974)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="RE" value="262">Reunion (+262)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="RO" value="40">Romania (+40)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="RU" value="7">Russia (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="RW" value="250">Rwanda (+250)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SM" value="378">San Marino (+378)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ST" value="239">Sao Tome &amp; Principe (+239)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SA" value="966">Saudi Arabia (+966)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SN" value="221">Senegal (+221)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CS" value="381">Serbia (+381)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SC" value="248">Seychelles (+248)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SL" value="232">Sierra Leone (+232)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SG" value="65">Singapore (+65)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SK" value="421">Slovak Republic (+421)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SI" value="386">Slovenia (+386)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SB" value="677">Solomon Islands (+677)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SO" value="252">Somalia (+252)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ZA" value="27">South Africa (+27)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ES" value="34">Spain (+34)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="LK" value="94">Sri Lanka (+94)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SH" value="290">St. Helena (+290)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="KN" value="1869">St. Kitts (+1869)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SC" value="1758">St. Lucia (+1758)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SD" value="249">Sudan (+249)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SR" value="597">Suriname (+597)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SZ" value="268">Swaziland (+268)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SE" value="46">Sweden (+46)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="CH" value="41">Switzerland (+41)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="SI" value="963">Syria (+963)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TW" value="886">Taiwan (+886)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TJ" value="7">Tajikstan (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TH" value="66">Thailand (+66)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TG" value="228">Togo (+228)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TO" value="676">Tonga (+676)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TT" value="1868">Trinidad &amp; Tobago (+1868)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TN" value="216">Tunisia (+216)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TR" value="90">Turkey (+90)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TM" value="7">Turkmenistan (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TM" value="993">Turkmenistan (+993)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TC" value="1649">Turks &amp; Caicos Islands (+1649)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="TV" value="688">Tuvalu (+688)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="UG" value="256">Uganda (+256)</option>
    <!-- <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK (+44)</option> -->
    <option data-countryCode="UA" value="380">Ukraine (+380)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AE" value="971">United Arab Emirates (+971)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="UY" value="598">Uruguay (+598)</option>
    <!-- <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">USA (+1)</option> -->
    <option data-countryCode="UZ" value="7">Uzbekistan (+7)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VU" value="678">Vanuatu (+678)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VA" value="379">Vatican City (+379)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VE" value="58">Venezuela (+58)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VN" value="84">Vietnam (+84)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VG" value="84">Virgin Islands - British (+1284)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="VI" value="84">Virgin Islands - US (+1340)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="WF" value="681">Wallis &amp; Futuna (+681)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="YE" value="969">Yemen (North)(+969)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="YE" value="967">Yemen (South)(+967)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ZM" value="260">Zambia (+260)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="ZW" value="263">Zimbabwe (+263)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Icewine. Your method still can't work. I've edited the css style. Can you check for me? Thanks.

Comment: I have added your css as you wrote it. It must be your parent container css that is causing the problem. If you run just this code it works fine as you can see.